# div appears below iframe on windows computer

Tags: css, flash, html, iframe

So I need to create a website that has an iframe, navigation and logo.

So the iframe's src is an html file, that html file contains a panorama which is a flash video. So I used z-index so that the iframe is below my div that contains the nav and logo. It works on Chrome, Firefox, Safari if I'm using a Mac. Then I tried testing the website on a windows computer and the website renders perfectly on Chrome only. Firefox, Safari,and IE position the div below the iframe (thus making my whole div not visible)

I did my research. Apparently flash videos are not affected by the z-index value? And I can't try to change the flash's wmode cos it's on a third party.

Any solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: So I need to see the site. Or, even better, a small, self-contained example that shows the issue, for instance on http://jsFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Build div container for your iframe and give it the z-index.

HTML

```
<div id="iframe">
    <iframe src="#">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#iframe { z-index: 10000; }
```

Comment: That doesn't help. z-indexes only work on positioned elements.

Comment: Of course he would have to position it. That was just a stripped down example of applying the z-index to the div. I typed out width: iframe-width; and height: iframe-height; but it seemed a little out of place.